# How to use ckan gem Comprehensive Knowledge Archive Network

Tags: ruby, rubygems, ckan

Does anyone have a link to a tutorial on how to use the Ruby 'ckan' gem (Comprehensive Knowledge Archive Network). I want to access gov.uk data , I downloaded the gem but how do I get to the data ? The documentation seems a bit sparse in this area

Many thanks for any help. My googling has turned up nothing so far so any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The CKAN gem's documentation is in their repository at https://github.com/apohllo/ckan. Note that it's not OKFN's CKAN repository.

Looking at their code, it seems that they hardcoded http://datahub.io API endpoint at https://github.com/apohllo/CKAN/blob/master/lib/ckan.rb#L2. So you won't be able to access data.gov.uk without changing their code.

But, thanks to Ruby being such a dynamic language, you could override that constant, as

```ruby
CKAN::API_BASE = 'http://data.gov.uk/api/1'
```

Now you could follow their documentation in GitHub, and it should work.

Cheers!